# Disable console logging for a class but enable file logging for this class in quarkus

Tags: logging, quarkus

I created logger in a class with logger name "transaction", and enabled file logging for it and its working logs are being written in the file, but it should not be shown in console, how to turn off this "transaction" logger for console while writing logs in a file?

this property completely turns off logging for this category
quarkus.log.category."transaction".level=OFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.console-handlers-console-handlers

You have the following option, which allows you to enable, or disable console logging:

```
quarkus.log.handler.console."console-handlers".enable
```

> If console logging should be enabled
>
> Environment variable:
> QUARKUS_LOG_HANDLER_CONSOLE__CONSOLE_HANDLERS__ENABLE

Therefore, try:

Create Console Handler for package and disable Console logging for this:

```
quarkus.log.category."your.package.for.logging".use-parent-handlers=false
quarkus.log.category."your.package.for.logging".level=INFO
quarkus.log.category."your.package.for.logging".handlers=TRANSACTION_HANDLER


quarkus.log.handler.console."TRANSACTION_HANDLER".enable = false
```

If you want to disable console logging for all:

```
quarkus.log.console.enable=false
```